# How to Reset Ethernet Network Connection?

Tags: network, sharing, file-sharing, ethernet, home-sharing

I use Ethernet network connections at home to create fast home network transferring files between my macs. One of the biggest problem I found is often that one mac cannot see another. It shows "connection failed" in network and there is a "connect as" button that does nothing when I click on it. It's funny because while say my macbook pro cannot see my iMac, my iMac can freely access my macbook pro. The only way to resolve this is to restart my macbook pro - which is very inconvenient. Is there a way to quickly reset the network connection without rebooting my computer? Thanks.

Comment: Okay here is a ghetto solution I have so far. I use the terminal's man mount_afp "ip address" to manually mount the network drive. Well, it's not the best solution either because obviously - I have to do it manually.

Comment: Are you connecting the 2 computers directly or is there a hub/router in the middle?  Is there anything interesting in Console?  Could this be related to sleep settings?

Comment: What happens if you try: deleted the preferences for the locations in the network panel and reset PRAM.

Comment: How do you deleted the preferences for the locations in the network panel and reset PRAM?